# How to actually fix the postfix Ops issue

Tags: scala

I have found several questions on the subject of the Scala compiler warning:

> postfix operator xxx should be enabled by making the implicit value
>   scala.language.postfixOps visible. This can be achieved by adding the
>   import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps' or by setting the
>   compiler option -language:postfixOps. See the Scala docs for value
>   scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion why the feature should be
>   explicitly enabled.

Here's an example of where this warning shows up:

```
val m1 = List(1->"a",2->"b") toMap
```

None really answered what I wanted to know when I first came across this problem: how do I fix this problem *without* involving the import or the compiler option. My first thought was this: if it doesn't like postfix ops, then make the method/op call *explicit* by replacing the space with a dot. For example:

```
val m1 = List(1->"a",2->"b").toMap
```

Unfortunately, when I first tried that fix, the code that I happened to be working on at the time looked something like this:

```
val m2 = List(1->"a",2->"b") map {case (k,v) => (k.toString,v)} toMap
```

When I added the dot, this resulted in yet another obscure compiler error:

```
val m2 = List(1->"a",2->"b") map {case (k,v) => (k.toString,v)}.toMap
```

> missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an
>   anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was: ?

which related to the *k* and *v* identifiers.

Back then, I just gave up and added the import statement and all was well. However, a student recently asked me about this issue and I thought I'd better go back and investigate. See my answer to the problem which, now that I think about it, is rather obvious. Yet I hope to save some others the time that it takes to wade through all of the other discussions of this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do in this situation, I'll add a dot to the first call:

```
val m2 = List(1->"a",2->"b").map {case (k,v) => (k.toString,v)}.toMap
```

Personally, I prefer this to having extra parenthesis.

Comment: Indeed, that works too. Perhaps it is slightly more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The answer has to do with the associativity of the operators ("." binds more tightly than map). The answer of course is to override the binding with parentheses:

```
  val m2 = (List(1->"a",2->"b") map {case (k,v) => (k.toString,v)}).toMap
```